# Ubuntu Touch - Unav offline tiles - can Foxtrot GPS tiles be used?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, gps

At last Unav has been configured to allow map tiles to be stored in the phones memory. Has anyone tried to load tiles from Foxtrot GPS or are the file protocols or file names different? Details of offline mapping for Unav here - [Unav.me](http://unav.me)

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is  - you can use the map tiles from FoxtrotGPS - you just need to copy them from your PC to your phone downloads and then move them to navigator.costales using the move command in the phone terminal

> mv ~/Downloads/maps ~/.local/share/navigator.costales